# How split the data frame when two consecutive cell values(string) in the column are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split the data frame when two or more consecutive cell values(string) in the column are the same.
Before: [Initial Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luS5r.png)
After/expected: [After the split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu9a9.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

data: `{'AuthorName': {0: 'Aeschylus', 1: 'Aeschylus', 2: 'Aeschylus', 3: 'Aeschylus', 4: 'Aeschylus', 5: 'Aeschylus', 6: 'Aeschylus', 7: 'Aeschylus', 8: 'Aeschylus', 9: 'Aeschylus', 10: 'Aeschylus', 11: 'Aeschylus', 12: 'Aeschylus', 13: 'Aeschylus', 14: 'Aeschylus', 15: 'Aeschylus', 16: 'Aeschylus', 17: 'Aeschylus', 18: 'Aeschylus', 19: 'Aeschylus', 20: 'Aeschylus', 21: 'Aeschylus', 22: 'Aeschylus', 23: 'Aeschylus', 24: 'Aeschylus', 25: 'Aeschylus', 26: 'Aeschylus', 27: 'Aeschylus', 28: 'Aeschylus', 29: 'Aeschylus', 30: 'Aeschylus', 31: 'Aeschylus', 32: 'Aeschylus', 33: 'Aeschylus', 34: 'Aeschylus', 35: 'Aeschylus', 36: 'Aeschylus', 37: 'Aeschylus', 38: 'Aeschylus', 39: 'Aeschylus'}, 'PlayName': {0: 'Agamemnon', 1: 'Agamemnon', 2: 'Agamemnon', 3: 'Agamemnon', 4: 'Agamemnon', 5: 'Agamemnon', 6: 'Agamemnon', 7: 'Agamemnon', 8: 'Agamemnon', 9: 'Agamemnon', 10: 'Agamemnon', 11: 'Agamemnon', 12: 'Agamemnon', 13: 'Agamemnon', 14: 'Agamemnon', 15: 'Agamemnon', 16: 'Agamemnon', 17: 'Agamemnon', 18: 'Agamemnon', 19: 'Agamemnon', 20: 'Agamemnon', 21: 'Agamemnon', 22: 'Agamemnon', 23: 'Agamemnon', 24: 'Agamemnon', 25: 'Agamemnon', 26: 'Agamemnon', 27: 'Agamemnon', 28: 'Agamemnon', 29: 'Agamemnon', 30: 'Agamemnon', 31: 'Agamemnon', 32: 'Agamemnon', 33: 'Agamemnon', 34: 'Agamemnon', 35: 'Agamemnon', 36: 'Agamemnon', 37: 'Agamemnon', 38: 'Agamemnon', 39: 'Agamemnon'}, 'ParagraphNumber': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15, 15: 16, 16: 17, 17: 18, 18: 19, 19: 20, 20: 21, 21: 22, 22: 23, 23: 24, 24: 25, 25: 26, 26: 27, 27: 28, 28: 29, 29: 30, 30: 31, 31: 32, 32: 33, 33: 34, 34: 35, 35: 36, 36: 37, 37: 38, 38: 39, 39: 40}, 'CharacterName': {0: 'Watchman', 1: 'Chorus', 2: 'Chorus', 3: 'Chorus', 4: 'Chorus', 5: 'Clytaemestra', 6: 'Chorus', 7: 'Clytaemestra', 8: 'Chorus', 9: 'Chorus', 10: 'Chorus', 11: 'Chorus', 12: 'OneElder', 13: 'Chorus_Leader', 14: 'AnotherElder', 15: 'Herald', 16: 'Chorus', 17: 'Herald', 18: 'Chorus', 19: 'Herald', 20: 'Chorus', 21: 'Herald', 22: 'Chorus', 23: 'Herald', 24: 'Chorus', 25: 'Chorus', 26: 'Chorus', 27: 'Chorus', 28: 'Chorus', 29: 'Chorus', 30: 'Chorus', 31: 'Chorus', 32: 'Chorus', 33: 'Agamemnon', 34: 'Clytaemestra', 35: 'Agamemnon', 36: 'Clytaemestra', 37: 'Agamemnon', 38: 'Clytaemestra', 39: 'Agamemnon'}}`

Comment: What is the criteria for splitting?

Comment: @Luke, two or more consecutive cell values(strings) should be the same

Comment: Please use `df.to_dict()` and post the output here so we can reproduce your df

Comment: please don't use images to  provide code/ data examples  see :https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @Luke, I have added data. Let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: @Nath, thanks for sharing the link. I am new to the community. I will take care this next time

Comment: getting closer butI'm  still not sure what you want try and cut the before and after dat sets down to the minimum needed to demonstrate  the problem.

Comment: @Nath, the dataset is about a play in the literature. I want to split the data frame as segments when the same 'Character' appears more than once in a row. When the same  'Character' appears more than once in a row, that is a segment. After that, another segment until the same 'Character' appears more than once in a row. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I have tried the following option. But I could not achieve what I need `data['Segment_check'] = (data['CharacterName'] == data.shift()['CharacterName'])`

Comment: why is `segment3` considered a new segment? Clytaemestra->Chorus->Clytaemestra does not have two names in a row (and this seems to be true of several segments)

Comment: @tdy, after **segment2**, until I get the same pattern(like **segment4**), I need to mark it as another segment. Here the pattern is like **segment2, segment4, segment6** (repeating the same character more than once).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby((df.CharacterName != df.CharacterName.shift()).cumsum())[
    "CharacterName"
].transform("count")

df["segment"] = "Segment" + (
    df.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).ngroup() + 1
).astype(str)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   AuthorName   PlayName  ParagraphNumber  CharacterName   segment
0   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                1       Watchman  Segment1
1   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                2         Chorus  Segment2
2   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                3         Chorus  Segment2
3   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                4         Chorus  Segment2
4   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                5         Chorus  Segment2
5   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                6   Clytaemestra  Segment3
6   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                7         Chorus  Segment3
7   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                8   Clytaemestra  Segment3
8   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                9         Chorus  Segment4
9   Aeschylus  Agamemnon               10         Chorus  Segment4
10  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               11         Chorus  Segment4
11  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               12         Chorus  Segment4
12  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               13       OneElder  Segment5
13  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               14  Chorus_Leader  Segment5
14  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               15   AnotherElder  Segment5
15  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               16         Herald  Segment5
16  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               17         Chorus  Segment5
17  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               18         Herald  Segment5
18  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               19         Chorus  Segment5
19  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               20         Herald  Segment5
20  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               21         Chorus  Segment5
21  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               22         Herald  Segment5
22  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               23         Chorus  Segment5
23  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               24         Herald  Segment5
24  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               25         Chorus  Segment6
25  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               26         Chorus  Segment6
26  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               27         Chorus  Segment6
27  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               28         Chorus  Segment6
28  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               29         Chorus  Segment6
29  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               30         Chorus  Segment6
30  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               31         Chorus  Segment6
31  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               32         Chorus  Segment6
32  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               33         Chorus  Segment6
33  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               34      Agamemnon  Segment7
34  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               35   Clytaemestra  Segment7
35  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               36      Agamemnon  Segment7
36  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               37   Clytaemestra  Segment7
37  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               38      Agamemnon  Segment7
38  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               39   Clytaemestra  Segment7
39  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               40      Agamemnon  Segment7
```

---

EDIT: To do a segmentation only for the name "Chorus"

```py
x = df.groupby((df.CharacterName != df.CharacterName.shift()).cumsum())[
    "CharacterName"
].transform("count")
x *= df.CharacterName.eq("Chorus") & (x > 1)

df["segment"] = "Segment" + (
    df.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).ngroup() + 1
).astype(str)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   AuthorName   PlayName  ParagraphNumber  CharacterName   segment
0   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                1       Watchman  Segment1
1   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                2         Chorus  Segment2
2   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                3         Chorus  Segment2
3   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                4         Chorus  Segment2
4   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                5         Chorus  Segment2
5   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                6   Clytaemestra  Segment3
6   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                7         Chorus  Segment3
7   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                8   Clytaemestra  Segment3
8   Aeschylus  Agamemnon                9         Chorus  Segment4
9   Aeschylus  Agamemnon               10         Chorus  Segment4
10  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               11         Chorus  Segment4
11  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               12         Chorus  Segment4
12  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               13       OneElder  Segment5
13  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               14  Chorus_Leader  Segment5
14  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               15   AnotherElder  Segment5
15  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               16         Herald  Segment5
16  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               17         Chorus  Segment5
17  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               18         Herald  Segment5
18  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               19         Chorus  Segment5
19  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               20         Herald  Segment5
20  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               21         Chorus  Segment5
21  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               22         Herald  Segment5
22  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               23         Chorus  Segment5
23  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               24         Herald  Segment5
24  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               25         Chorus  Segment6
25  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               26         Chorus  Segment6
26  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               27         Chorus  Segment6
27  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               28         Chorus  Segment6
28  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               29         Chorus  Segment6
29  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               30         Chorus  Segment6
30  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               31         Chorus  Segment6
31  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               32         Chorus  Segment6
32  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               33         Chorus  Segment6
33  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               34      Agamemnon  Segment7
34  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               35      Agamemnon  Segment7
35  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               36      Agamemnon  Segment7
36  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               37   Clytaemestra  Segment7
37  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               38      Agamemnon  Segment7
38  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               39   Clytaemestra  Segment7
39  Aeschylus  Agamemnon               40      Agamemnon  Segment7
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. It worked best for the posted problem. 
But I need segmentation for only one character **Chorus**. Can you suggest any solution for that? In the data frame, sometimes other characters(e.g, Agamemnon) are repeated. I want to ignore that case.

Comment: it worked like magic. Thank you for the solution and quick response.
What `x *= df.CharacterName.eq("Chorus") & (x > 1)` is doing?

Comment: @Vijaya With `x *= df.CharacterName.eq("Chorus") & (x > 1)` I *mask* only groups with name "Chorus" that have count greater than 1. Then I split the dataframe along these groups.

Comment: Wow, that's a great idea. I could not think of it. Thank you, @Andrej Kesely, for the update.